# Execute unix shell script file from windows OS

Tags: bash, unix, sh

hi as my question says i am trying to do this with Plink installed on my windows box.I try to execute command on windows CMD according to plink syntax but getting below error-:

**Command-:**

```
@"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh abcd@somehostname -pw @123# -m /u/siebel/abcd/running.sh;
```

**Error-:**

Unable to open file **running.sh**

> I have given 777 permission to my file running.sh on unix box.

Can anyone help me on this or provide me any idea?? What can be wrong with above syntax?

Comment: Try to enclose your password with quote signs, because # is beginning of comment in bash

Comment: About the error, have tou tried something simple like ls? Maybe there is problem with the file or the path to it

Comment: assuming the path is correct is the parent folder /u/siebel/abcd accessible to the user ?

Answer (score 0):

The "-m" argument to plink specifies a local file with commands to run on the remote host.  Remove that from your command line, and leave the name of your remote shell script as the last argument (with no preceding flag.)